# Excel Match function is causing an error even though the values clearly match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match

There is no way that this should be an error. There are no hidden spaces, and picture 3 clearly shows that Excel sees both words as the same. Could the slanting of my word in picture 3 be the problem?

I downloaded this spreadsheet from Simplemaps.org

[image: Evaluation step 1]

[image: Evaluation step 2]

[image: Evaluation step 3]

Comment: Try changing the last 0 to 1 (exact match)

Comment: Hi, Oki. What's the context? Can you detail some values and addresses? What is the desired result with this function?

Comment: Regardless of if I put 1-,0, or 1 it still gives an error. In my Excel, it is saying that 0 is for an exact match.

Comment: The desired result is to have the formula return a 1 since it is looking at only 2 values and the matching value is in the first index of the range.

Comment: I don't think MATCH is case-sensitive. So the UPPER is redundant. If you want a case-sensitive match, see [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/exact-match-lookup-with-index-and-match).

Comment: @BigBen You are right. Removing UPPER fixed everything. Coincidentally I was using that website to learn the Match function. Thank you and everyone who joined to help.

Comment: Turns out italics(slanting) is just the evaluator helping you locate the most recent change.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to find matching entries in a matrix, or matching text in cells? I believe that the function you're looking for is `=exact("SURFFOLK", upper(lookup$j$517))`

Comment: I  have two lists of cities. In column J  I have the lookup list, and in column A I have the search list. I want to use the match function to get indexes in column A. But right now I am hardcoding one value to see why the match function isn't working.

Comment: @OkiOgbe - get rid of the UPPER then.

Comment: Thank you @BigBen . I thought that I needed to use upper because Suffolk in A517 was all lower case, but my lookup value is in all Caps. Removing UPPER fixed everything.